# SAP GUI Script Runs Slower Over Time VBA

Tags: excel, vba, performance, scripting, sap-gui

When I run a SAP GUI script in VBA (excel) over a long period of time, the SAP GUI session starts to slow down. If I interrupt the code and start it again, the SAP GUI session still runs at the slow speed it was at. If I close Excel and run the code again, the SAP GUI session still runs at the slow speed. However, if I close the SAP GUI session and reopen it and then run the code (not closing Excel), the speed goes back to optimal speed again.

I ran the below code (as a test) to see the speed decrease. When the code started, each loop took about 4 seconds, by the 300th loop however, the speed decreased to 16 seconds per loop.

This may seem trivial, but I am running another block of code (too big to post) which has about 3000 loops to perform, where each loop takes about 25 seconds to perform at optimal speed (a minute or longer per loop once SAP GUI starts to slow down).

Rather than running a block of 100 loops, closing SAP GUI, reopening SAP GUI again and then running the next block of 100 loops (which is what I have been doing), does anybody know what slows down the SAP GUI session and if there is a way to reset SAP programmatically so that the code returns to optimal speed again? Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated, I couldn’t find much on the internet regarding this.

```
Sub runScript()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Dim count As Integer
    count = 1
    
    Do While count < 1000
    
        Dim startDateTime As Date
        startDateTime = Now

        Call enterExitTransactionIW33
        
        Cells(count, 2) = DateDiff("S", startDateTime, Now)
        count = count + 1
    
    Loop
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub

Private Sub enterExitTransactionIW33()

    Dim SAPGuiAuto, SAPApp, SAPConnection, SAPSession As Object
    
    Set SAPGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
    Set SAPApp = SAPGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
    Set SAPConnection = SAPApp.Children(0)
    Set SAPSession = SAPConnection.Children(0)

    SAPSession.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "IW33"
    SAPSession.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
    
    SAPSession.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtCAUFVD-AUFNR").Text = "80808080"
    SAPSession.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
    
    SAPSession.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB_ALL:SAPLCOIH:3001/ssubSUB_LEVEL:SAPLCOIH:1100/tabsTS_1100/tabpVGUE").Select
    SAPSession.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB_ALL:SAPLCOIH:3001/ssubSUB_LEVEL:SAPLCOIH:1101/tabsTS_1100/tabpMUEB").Select
    SAPSession.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB_ALL:SAPLCOIH:3001/ssubSUB_LEVEL:SAPLCOIH:1101/tabsTS_1100/tabpKOAU").Select
    SAPSession.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB_ALL:SAPLCOIH:3001/ssubSUB_LEVEL:SAPLCOIH:1101/tabsTS_1100/tabpPARU").Select
    SAPSession.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB_ALL:SAPLCOIH:3001/ssubSUB_LEVEL:SAPLCOIH:1101/tabsTS_1100/tabpIOLU").Select
    SAPSession.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUB_ALL:SAPLCOIH:3001/ssubSUB_LEVEL:SAPLCOIH:1101/tabsTS_1100/tabpIHKD").Select
    
    SAPSession.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/N"
    SAPSession.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I already noticed the described statement about 10 years ago. I did not find a solution at the time. Therefore, I signed off from SAP with a lot of loops (about 20,000) by script. A login took place again by script and the execution continued at the noted place. Everything went without me having to intervene manually.

Comment: Hi ScriptMan, thanks for your reply. I’ve now implemented a log off/ on into my code when speed drops by half, log off/ on takes a little bit of time (no really much time 10-20 secs), but overall speed is faster. Only main now downfall is I can’t use the other SAP sessions while it’s running, as they will eventually shut down with the log off/ on. The small compromise is still better though, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem and I couldn't find an answer anywhere, but I believe I found a workaround for this - all you need to do is to wait 1 second when the script slows down:

```
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
```

The first step was to measure how much time it takes to execute each loop, so I calculated it like this:

```
For i = 1 To 100
    StartTime = Timer  

    [SAP GUI Script] 

    SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)
Next
```

Based on SecondsElapsed variable, I could tell that after the 10th loop, the script slowed down, so I need to wait 1 second every 10 loops.

```
breakCount = 0
For i = 1 To 100
  breakCount = breakCount + 1
  StartTime = Timer  

  [SAP GUI Script] 
              
  SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)

  If breakCount = 10 Then
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    breakCount = 0
  End If
Next
```

And that solved the problem for me.