# SAP running slower after accessing 500 times via Automation Anywhere

Tags: rpa, sap-gui, automationanywhere

I'm using RPA tools called Automation Anywhere v11.0 to export data as Excel from SAP system via SAP GUI. After that I need to go through each record in the Excel file to retrieve additional data from SAP system and put them back to the Excel. I'm using Metabot to process SAP actions.

The problem is SAP running slower after 500th records (approx.).

For example, the first 100 records running speed is 10 records/minute but it takes 7 records/minute after 550th record.

Do I need to clear temp file or cache or something like that to make SAP running in normal speed.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you check if CPU and memory consumption during the robot run? Does it increase?

Comment: @MarekStejskal CPU is between 40%-100% and memory is quite stable at 49%. I notice that the CPU increase when using Metabot or VBScript.

Comment: It would be interesting to know whether it's a problem with the Metabots, scripts or SAP. Can you make an exact copy of the metabot and write your robot to run a portion of cases with the old one and then using the new one? It's important that it's part of one, uninterrupted task. If it gets faster then the metabot is leaking somewhere.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54178988/sap-script-runs-slower-over-time-vba

Answer (score 1):

Check Whether Excel processes were disposed completely. If not, you should kill those processes.

Answer (score 1):

try disabling the systems logging and also Remove the SystemLog.xml from Application path if it exists.

[image: options panel]